# Installing Ubuntu 15.10 on Windows10

Tags: system-installation

I recently downloaded the installer for Ubuntu version 15.10 and I can't seem to find the installation icon in the folder after I unzip the file.
Any help would be nice and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you download the file, use [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to burn the ISO image to a DVD or [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) to transfer it to a USB flash drive.